# Модуль комментариев для kohana 3.2

Tags: kohana

Кто нибудь знает модуль комментариев для kohana 3.2? В интернете не нашел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Легче самому написать. Или использовать стороннее решение, например [Disqus](http://disqus.com/).

Answer (score 1):

Есть еще более удобное стороннее решение (русскоязычное):[Комментируем фрагмент текста](http://hypercomments.com/ru) устанавливаешь бесплатный вариант... Ставишь те функции, которые тебе нужны и вперед.

Answer (score 0):

В кохане из-коробки нет модулей постов, статей, форума и т.д.
Поэтому готового универсального модуля комментариев не найти. Они пишутся под конкретный функционал.

Пишите с нуля модуль под свои нужды. Либо используйте готовые решения общего плана, напр. Disqus как посоветовал codefucker.